# JSLint a constructor name should not start with a lowercase letter

Tags: javascript, syntax, coding-style, standards, jslint

I'm getting the following JSLint `error: A constructor name should not start with a lowercase letter`. I get this error when it encounters an identifier starting with a lowercase letter preceded by the `new` operator.

I have a model called `MyModel` that contains a function `this.doSomething = function();`

in my controller I access that function:

```
self.myModel = MyModel;
var newModel = new self.myModel.doSomething();
```

Although this works i take it from the JSLint error that `doSomething()` should be `DoSomething()`

although `this.DoSomething = function()` seems like incorrect syntax to me. My question is, what is the best practice syntax to remove this error?

Comment: I think it's suggesting that it should be `new MyModel`, not `new self.myModal`

Comment: Using a property to hold a constructor is probably unusual, so he doesn't recognize this special case.

Comment: I'm a little suspicious of the naming conventions you're using, but fwiw it does work as written on jslint.com and old.jslint.com, though I'd agree with @Barmar that it probably should complain